# Good icon theme for programming?

Tags: icons

I can't find any GNOME icon theme that highlights source code files, especially C and C++.
Any suggestion ?

Edit.
I tried NITRUX, it doesn't have the icons for languages (C, C++, etc).
Oxygen does have the icons, although I don't much like the looks of it.
I sometimes use NouveGnome, but its support for languages is small.

Well, I think Oxygen will have to do for now.

Thanks ppl.

Comment: What do you mean with *highlight* files?. An example would be nice.

Comment: @UriHerrera I guess he wants an icon which makes it clear that the file is a c++ file, like a .rar file has its winrar icon.

Comment: Yeah @Ahatius I was assuming that but wanted clarification from the OP, try [this](http://fav.me/d4utllr) maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Install Ubuntu Tweak and change the Icon Theme to "Oxygen"

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely no need to install Ubuntu Tweak, There's Advanced Settings for that.