# No File Type Icon

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, icons

I work with a lot of files and I need file type icons to identify the file types. However, on my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS GNOME, I don't have file type icons. For example test.c does not show the normal icon.[image: Image icon]

On my machine it looks like this:[image: Image icon 2]

How do I fix this?

Comment: i guess this has something to do with the theme you use, there are themes, that have for every mime type it's own symbol and others didn't invest all that work;

Comment: @db429 Not even. The second screenshot is my default installation of my Ubuntu. I have't changed the theme since I installed it. I tried other themes, but it didn't help.

Comment: try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/236260/good-icon-theme-for-programming ; btw you will need gnome-tweak not unity-tweak

Comment: @db429 Interesting. How is it that this Oxygen has c and c++ icon files while the main Adwata icon theme doesn't?

Comment: read my first comment:  some don't do that work aka are lazy people

Comment: Okay, so if I were to copy the mime files from another Ubuntu, say Ubuntu(Unity), would that help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the Faenza Icon set http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faenza-Icons-173323228

to install it open a terminal and enter:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme`

now activate it with following command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme Faenza`

alternatively you can also install gnome-tweak-tool via `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` and change the settings in there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I am pushing this a little bit, but can you find one that is flat and modern, more like Numix or Papirus?

Comment: I will try this though.

Comment: hey sorry but, go look for yourself, here is a link to start of http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/9-beautiful-alternatives-default-linux-icons/ __ btw u are pushing this tremendously - I shall put in the work to find you an icon set, where someone put in the work to represent the different mime-types? how about you put in the work to find what you like?

Comment: I actually did. I got the [mono dark flattr theme](https://github.com/EmptyStackExn/mono-dark-flattr-icons). It had the icon types.

Comment: okay, misunderstood you in your first comment on the question, yet my 'theme' might not have been quiet precisely